# zsh: command not found: react-create-app

Tags: shell, reactjs

I wanted to create a new React project with the `create-react-app` command. However after installing it I got this error: `zsh: command not found: react-create-app`. I searched online a little and I think my problem has to do with the `~./bash_profile` file.

The problem is that I have no idea how a bash_profile file should be setup so I wanted to ask you guys here at Stack overflow. Here's my bash_file:
[image]

I'm wondering if something is out of it's place here and if it has to do with my error.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how exactly you installed `create-react-app`. Also, the `.bash_profile` file is used by the Bash shell, not by the ZSH that you're using (there's ` ~/.zprofile` for that)

Comment: I followed this guide: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#getting-started . That's how I installed it. And I did not know that hehe. Apparently I have no such file as ` ~/.zprofile`.

Comment: In that case, it's likely to be installed as `/usr/local/bin/create-react-app`. I would assume that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`, though.

Comment: This is really frustrating. >:(

Comment: Try and see if using it by its full path works.